# keys and values from an ajax POST are all escaped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, post

I am trying to access some params from an ajax post in Rails. But my params are all escaped. I am not quite whether this is the best way to go about it. If I inspect the `params[:event]` vairable in Rails I end up receiving it looks something like this

```
{\"title\":\"None\",\"startdate\":\"2014-01-23\",\"enddate\":\"None\",\"description\":\" Description\"}
```

I am sure I can use this data if I really wanted to. But is this really the best way to receive data on my backend?

For reference, ajax

```
$.ajax ({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/calendar',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'event': JSON.stringify(this)},

    success: function(response) {
        console.log('Success ', response);
    }

});
```

Typical data

```
event:{
    "title":"None",
    "startdate":"2014-01-23",
    "enddate":"None",
    "description":"Description"
}
```

Two questions:

1. Is this the only way rails would accept data?
2. If this is the safest way to post data to my backend what would be the easiest way of accessing the data?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON.stringify was the culprit. I was using a backbone model and switched to .toJSON instead.